# Push notification on database edit?

Tags: android, push-notification, push

is there a way to automatic send notification to user when the **value** field is edited on online database?

The table **user** is this:

- uid
- notifications (yes or not)
- value

When someone edit **value** through a php page, if **notifications** == "yes" I want to send the user a push notification.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the app to a webAPI and the webAPI can hold your data, in this way you could fire up a notification as soon as any data has been modified in the database.